# Polymorphic Association / Rails3 Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok,

I have a polymorphic Attachment model which is working okay when it's dependant of a Campaign model. This is working fine:

> > Campaign.last.attachments

I'm getting all the attachments of that campaign. But, I need to do it the other way around: Retrieve the parent object of an attachment (retrieve the campaign). I imagined it would be something like this.

> > Attachment.last.campaign

But I'm getting nil as result. The attachment object has attachable_id: 64, attachable_type: "Campaign".

I'm missing something here but I can't figure it out what.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [configured the polymorphic association correctly](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association):

```
some_attachment.attachable
```

Comment: remember to flag this as an answer.

Comment: @Aldo: frank was right, the previous link was dead, I updated it.  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4788228/revisions

Comment: Ah OK, when I tried the link was already to RailsCasts and worked